# border-radius помехи

Tags: css, firefox, обработка-ошибок, border, эксперименты

Вот простейший блок с заокругленным бордером в 0px. Но почему от ::after есть помехи, если у него z-index меньше? Снизу на картинках 3 эксперимента:
**1)** ::after 200x200px background-color:white;
**2)** ::after 2x2px background-color:white;
**3)** ::after 200x200px background-color:blue
[image: эксперименты]

Эксперимент доказывает, что:

**1)** Почему-то по углам есть маленькая часть, которая рисуется, но уже скрывает псевдоэлементы;

**2)** Почему то афтеру до лампочки, что у него z-index меньше и он по углам оставляет свой след;

**3)** Почемуто бифору не удаётся закрыть по углам афтер, хотя он сплошной квадрат без заокругленных углов

Вопрос: как мне это пофиксить? У меня элемент на сайте имеет двойную анимацию смещением псевдоэлементов, но по углам эти помехи портят очень.

браузер firefox, пк.

вот code эксперимента:

```css
body{
    background-color:black;
}
div{
    position:relative;
    content:"";
    margin:50px;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    border-radius:50px;
    background-color:white;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:0;
}
div::before{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color:blue;
    border:0;
}
div::after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color:white;
    border:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="qb1">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Потому что так ведёт себя смешивание белого и синего полупрозрачных пикселей. Похожий эффект можно легко повторить повторить в каком-нибудь фотошопе, наложив друг на друга два одинаковых квадрата разных цветов https://i.stack.imgur.com/1U107.png

Comment: Если по аналогии наложить красный и зелёный квадрат, то в смешивании полупрозрачных пикселей получится что-то похожее на оранжевый/жёлтый https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yx9UG.png

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я так и думал, что это из-за смешивания цветов. https://imgur.com/a/PwOja8n вот такая анимация когда включаешь/выключаешь квиз на сайте. Нету ли вариантов, как "победить" эти помехи на углах?

Comment: попробуйте изменять прозрачность, возможно сработает

Comment: Потом попробую обязательно. И у меня ещё одна идея: запихнуть в тот блок ещё один, чуть меньше, а основной, от которого псевдоелементы идут, сделать бэкграунд прозрачным. Думаю сработает. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решить можно, если обойтись без ::after (в моём случае ::before сделал через linear-gradient двухцветным), основной блок сделать прозрачным (спасибо за подсказки), а контент поместить в ещё один блок, который чуть меньше родителя и имеет отступ на пару пикселей от краёв. Тогда углы будут чистыми.